# can i change the column type of a DataTable after using data adapter to fill it

Tags: c#, ms-access

So, I am trying to change the column type of table to bool but I don't know if this is possible because I used data adapter to fill the table as in the following code

```
private void GetData(string selectCommand)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create a new data adapter based on the specified query.
                dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand, conn);

                OleDbCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

                // Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource.
                System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
                table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                dataAdapter.Fill(table);
                //table.Columns["Status"].DataType = typeof(bool);
                if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
                    bindingSource1.DataSource = table;
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("There is no such Data.", "No Result");
                    showAll();
                }

            }
```

as you can see the commented line was a wrong way. Can someone help?

Comment: My immediate thoughts are No. But you could always create a new data table with the types you need and populate that.

Comment: Don't use OleDbDataAdapter.Fill to populate DataTable. Data loss may occur without any notice, because the data type of the column is decided based on first 8 rows and the values of different types are read as null! Even IMEX=1 option will not help, because you need to have intermixed values in these first 8 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx) for your reference. Try changing the data type of the DataColumn using the GetType() method.

```
 DataColumn statusColumn = table.Columns["Status"];
 statusColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean");
```

Comment: I see, you are fetching the whole table from DB. Can you not change the schema definition of the table directly at a DB level?